# Gitlab snippets file access

Tags: gitlab

How can we access a snippet file from a Gitlab (private) repository?

I can access and clone my (private) projects (using SSH) but the problem with the snippets is that the raw URL doesn’t return the filename, let me give you an example:

```
I create a new snippet:
Title: My new patch
Access: Public (let’s say public to be clearer)
File: my_patch.patch (filename)
<code>….</code>
```

When I see the raw of the file it returns a URL like https://gitlab.com/snippets/id/raw but I need something like https://gitlab.com/snippets/id/my_patch.patch

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that sharing a private snippet is supported at this moment.

Check and push these feature proposals for having this enhancement:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/22337

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24318

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.